# Spring Boot Custom Query In Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How do i add a custom query to my Spring boot application and access it in the controller?

I have two tables called `CarBrand` and `YearMade`. `CarBrand` has `ID`, `code` and `Brand` as columns. `YearMade` also has `ID`, `code` and `year` as columns.

I have written my model classes with setter and getter methods for each entity.  I have added my repository interfaces and my service classes.

```
public interface YearRepository extends JpaRepository<Year, Long> {
}
```

My Brand Repository

```
public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long> {

    @Query("select b from brand b where brand.brand = ?1")
    List<Brand> findVehicleBrand(String brand);
}
```

Here is my service class

```
public class YearService {

    @Autowired
    private YearRepository yearRepository;

    public List<Year> listAll(){
        return yearRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Year engineSize){
       yearRepository.save(engineSize);
    }

    public Year get (long id){
        return yearRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void delete (Long id){
        yearRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

My Brand Service

```
public interface BService {

    List<Brand> findVehicleBrand(String name);

}
```

And this.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BrandService implements BService{

    @Autowired
    private BrandRepository brandRepository;

    public List<Brand> listAll(){
        return brandRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Brand brand){
        brandRepository.save(brand);
    }

    public Brand get (long id){
        return brandRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void delete (Long id){
        brandRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Brand> findVehicleBrand(String name) {
        var brand = (List<Brand>) brandRepository.findVehicleBrand(name);
        return brand;
    }
}
```

In my controller, I get a path variable with a string, i use `substring` to break the string into two. The two substrings have the code for brand and year. The first two represent the year and the other three represent the brand. How do i compare the codes to the codes in the database to get the actual year and brand.

http://localhost:8081/vincode/wwQPT

The ww is the code for the year 1990 and QPT is for  Honda Motor Company in the database.

I want a JSON response like this

```
{
    Year Made : 1990,
    Brand Name : Honda Motor Company
}
```

Here is the controller class i have so far.

```
@RequestMapping("/{vincode}")
public @ResponseBody String getAttr(@PathVariable(value="vincode") String vincode) {
    String yr = vincode.substring(0,1);
    String brand = vincode.substring(2,4);
    System.out.println(yr);
    return yr;
}
```

Where do i add the query and how do i use it in my controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA derives queries based on method naming conventions.
So, to get `year` by `code` in `YearMade` table, you need to modify your `YearReporsitory` interface like this (add an abstract method):

```
 public interface YearRepository extends JpaRepository<Year, Long> {
          // set return type as required
          //find - Do What, ByCode - Criteria.
        public Integer findByCode(String code);
        }
```

And, use this method in your `YearService` just as you've used other methods.
But, you cannot use the same method for getting brand by code requirement. You'll have to write a repo class for it like:

```
   public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<CarBrand, Long> {
            public Integer findByCode(String code);
   }
```

You can write these methods for all the members of your `Entity` class. You've to follow the naming convention to get Spring recognize it.

**EDIT** (to show how to use this in controller and service class): 
`YearRepository` interface:

```
public interface YearRepository extends JpaRepository<Year, Long> {
              // set return type as required
              //find - Do What, ByCode - Criteria.
            public Integer findByCode(String code);
            }
```

`BrandRepository`

```
public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long> {
 /*The below two methods are abstract methods.*/
   // it must follow the findby<MemberName> convention
   //return CarBrand
    CarBrand findByBrand(String brand);
    
    /*return a CarBrand Entity*/
    public CarBrand findByCode(String code);
```

`YearService`:

```
      public class YearService {

    @Autowired
    private YearRepository yearRepository;

    public List<Year> listAll() {
        return yearRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Year engineSize) {
        yearRepository.save(engineSize);
    }

    public Year get(long id) {
        return yearRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        yearRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public int getYearByCode(String code) {
     //here, we're using this method just as you've used the methods above.
    //Spring constructs the query at runtime
          return yearRepository.findByCode(code); //<-- usage of the custom method
    }

}
```

`BService`:

```
public interface BService {

    CarBrand findVehicleBrand(String name);

}
```

`BrandService`:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BrandService implements BService{

    @Autowired
    private BrandRepository brandRepository;

    public List<Brand> listAll(){
        return brandRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Brand brand){
        brandRepository.save(brand);
    }

    public Brand get (long id){
        return brandRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void delete (Long id){
        brandRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public CarBrand findVehicleBrand(String name) {
        //var brand = (List<Brand>) brandRepository.findVehicleBrand(name);  
         var brand = brandRepository.findByBrand(name); //<-- using the custom method in brandRepository
        return brand;
    }
}
```

Your `RepsonseDto`:

```
  class RepsonseDto {
   
    private String yearMade;
    private brandName;
    
    //getters and setters
    /*Use  @JsonProperty("Year Made") and  @JsonProperty("Brand Name") on your getters. Otherwise, you will get json reposnse as: "yearMade" and "brandName"*/
    }
```

Controller:

**There are better ways to write controllers and inject dependencies.** Let's keep it simple for now.

```
  @RequestController
    class YourController {
    
    //inject dependencies
    
    @Autowired
    YearService yearService;
    
    @Autowired
    BrandService brandService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/{vincode}")
    // the definition for ResponseEntity is above
    public ResponseEntity<RepsonseDto> getAttr(@PathVariable(value="vincode") String vincode) {
       // create a ReponseEntity object
       RepsonseDto retEntity = new RepsonseDto();
       
     
       // do a check for null and expected length of vincode
        if(vincode != null && vincode.length() == 5) {
        String yr = vincode.substring(0,1);
        String brand = vincode.substring(2,4);

        retEntity.setYearMade(yearService.getYearByCode(yr));
        retEntity.setBrandName(brandService.findVehicleBrand(brand));
  
        System.out.println(yr);
     
    }

 return new ResponseEntity<>(retEntity, HttpStatus.OK)
    
    }
```

**NOTE**: I didn't use an IDE to write this. There may be compiler errors. Hope this gives you an idea of it all fits in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But i dont know how that fits in. But this is the Brand Repository I have now.
`public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long> {

    @Query("select b from brand b where brand.brand = ?1")
    List<Brand> findVehicleBrand(String brand);
}`

Comment: @WinfredAdrah You don't need to to write a query when you're selecting by a member of your `entity`. Spring does that for you. So, when you want to _search your table by one of the members of your entity class_, you just let Spring know this by _findby<member name>_. It will create query on the fly. Only when you need queries that require join and complex conditions, you write custom query. More [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)

Comment: Ok, but how do i use that in the controller with the code i am writing?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have request mappong wlth value top of the class then http://localhost:8081/vincode/ww/QPT

RequestMapping("/vincode/{code}/{company}") can be more useful

There is no need to use substring maybe code or company key sizes changes.

Also service layer can be injected and used anytime.

Comment: How do i query the database?

Comment: Did you define relation with brand and year in entities?

Comment: It is better to define relationship but if it is not case then use findByCode method and find year object. You can use brandService to query with company.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add this statement in BrandRepository interface :

```
    public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<Brand, Long> {
    @Query("select b from brand b where brand.brand = ?1")
    List<Brand> findVehicleBrand(String brand);
    public Brand findByCode(String code);
}
```

In YearRepository interface :

```
public interface YearRepository extends JpaRepository<Year, Long> {
public Year findByCode(String code);
}
```

Then add this method in BrandService Class:

```
public String findByCode (String code){
        return brandRepository.findByCode(code).getBrand();
    }
```

Then add this method in YearService Class:

```
public String findByCode (String code){
        return yearRepository.findByCode(code).getYear;
    }
```

Create Domain Class :

```
public class YearBrand
{
   private String YearMade;
   private String BrandName;
   public YearBrand(String year, String brand)
   {
    this.YearMade=year;
    this.BrandName=brand;
    }
}
```

Then In Controller Class :

```
@RequestMapping("/{vincode}")
    public YearBrand getAttr(@PathVariable(value="vincode") String vincode) {
        String yr = vincode.substring(0,1);
        String brand = vincode.substring(2,4);
        return new YearBrand(yearService.findByCode(yr),brandService.findByCode(brand));
    }
```

NOTES:
Make sure your Controller Class is annotated with @RestController

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException: null. And a 500 internal Server Error

Comment: In Which Class you got null pointer exception tell me?